# ASP plain text file response is cut short

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP web forms page with a button. On postback the button sends some XML content back to the user as a file. It has been working however in one case with a string with a length of 16759 the downloaded file has been cut short by 10 bytes. Both Chrome and Firefox have exhibited the same behaviour.

The solution has been to change the content-type from "text/xml" (I also tried "text/plain") to "application/octet-stream". However I would like to understand why the other content-types behave in this way.

My code is as follows. (I've played around with a few different methods and they did not change anything)

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", content.Length.ToString());
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"test.txt\"");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(content);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
```

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is not call *Close* on the Stream.  Don't ask me for an explanation, all I know is it works.

Explanation per the [MSDN link for HttpResponse.Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.close.aspx) kindly provided by Ray Cheng:

> This method terminates the connection to the client in an abrupt manner and is not intended for normal HTTP request processing. The method sends a reset packet to the client, which can cause response data that is buffered on the server, the client, or somewhere in between to be dropped.

Comment: Here's 1 of the explanations. See Remarks. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.close.aspx

Comment: I can't do that from an aspx page because the page will output content after the file content. The correct approach might be to redirect the user to a HttpHandler which would output the content and then I could indeed omit the Close(). Regardless I would expect the octet-stream content-type to show the same behaviour with Close() yet it doesn't.